# validation regularexpression

Tags: asp.net

i have text box in that user have to enter only text. user shouldn't enter digits and special character also.help me thanku

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only letters and spaces, with at least one:
`^[A-Za-z ]+$`

Comment: thank u mr.Graham Clark. i have doubt this expression includes no special character.user should not enter  the special character also.